# Preload XML Animation in Fragment Transactions

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

In my application I'm doing the following (using the support library):

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
transaction.commit();
```

The animations `R.anim.fade_in` and `R.anim.fade_out` have less than 200 milliseconds duration.

The first time i change the fragment, the animation doesn't show at all. I think it is due to XML inflating: the time it takes to inflate XML is bigger than the duration of the animation. From the second time on, the animation displays correctly.

Is there a way to preload an XML animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it myself. You have to override the `onCreateAnimation()` method in your `Fragment`. This is how I did it:

```
@Override
public Animation onCreateAnimation(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim) {
    if (enter)
        return mEnterAnimation;
    else
        return mExitAnimation;
}

private static final Animation mEnterAnimation = AnimationUtils
    .loadAnimation(MyApplication.getInstance().getBaseContext(),
    R.anim.frag_fade_in);

private static final Animation mExitAnimation = AnimationUtils
    .loadAnimation(MyApplication.getInstance().getBaseContext(),
    R.anim.frag_fade_out);
```

Note that the `mEnterAnimation` and `mExitAnimation` fields are declared static. To load an animation via `AnimationUtils.loadAnimation()` you need a `Context`. The `Context` is obtained via the `MyApplication` singleton. To create such a singleton just write into your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <!-- Insert your activities here -->

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Then create the class `com.example.app.MyApplication` as a singleton:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public static MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    private static MyApplication mInstance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [AnimationUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationUtils.html) and more precisely at

```
loadAnimation(Context context, int id)
```

it should be what you need.
Also android already has anim for fade ins and fade outs android.R.anim.fade_in and android.R.anim.fade_out,you should try using those,maybe they prove to be more efficient.

Comment: It doesn't work. I know the built-ins `R.anim.fade_in` and `R.anim.fad_out` but I need faster animations. Thank you anyway.